# Lotus Domino Resolve Email Address (From, To)

Tags: java, lotus-domino

I've been fussing around with the Java API of Lotus Domino in order to export all Mails to eml. So far so good, but is there a method where i can automatically **"resolve"** Email-Addresses. The "From" or "To" Fields sometimes only gives me *CN=Max Mustermann/O=musterdomain*.

My exspected result would be something like this: *max.mustermann@musterdomain.de*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [LookupNames](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_LOOKUPNAMES_METHOD_DIRECTORY.html) method of the [NotesDirectory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESDIRECTORY_CLASS.html) class.  You can get an instance of NotesDirectory via the [GetDirectory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_GETDIRECTORY_METHOD.html) method of the [NotesSesson](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESSESSION_CLASS.html) class.  There are some examples [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_LOOKUPNAMES_METHOD.html). You'll want InternetAddress to be one of the items returned by your call.